# Replace all backslash escape sequence-producable characters with their escaped escape sequences

Tags: shell, perl, escape-characters, python3, ruby

EDIT: I'm very sorry, that I initially didn't make my requirements clear. I don't actually have access to the string written in a backslash-escaped way and have amended the example to make that clearer. The two answers that I got as of now require me to have backslashes in the string to begin with, which is not the case.

I have a string that may contain lots of difficult characters, which I want to write to a file in an escaped way, so that it would generate the same string if given in double-quotes to `echo -e`, `perl`, etc. I tried using `shell-quote` and perl's `quotemeta` function, but they do different quoting.

Example:

```
# I have a file containing difficult characters:
$ cat text
line0'field0
line1   field1"
$ cat -v text
line0'field0
line1   field1"
```

Expected raw output including the enclosing double-quotes:

```
"line0'field0\nline1\tfield1\""
```

I'm sure there must already be a built-in solution to this.

Comment: Why must there be one? After all, none of these interpret every escape sequence the same way.

Comment: Does `printf '%s\n' "$mystring"` not output the string in `$mystring` correctly?  I'm honestly a bit unsure what you want to do. Is the string the whole line from `doublequoted=` onwards?  Does "This is the type of string" refer to the whole following line or to some specific part of it?

Comment: @Kusalananda I should have written more clearly. I've edited my question now, let me know if there's still anything unclear.

Answer (score 1):

### Answer to revised wording

The only tool that comes to mind (and is widely available) is `sed`, and it's not exactly pretty.

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/\\n/g;s/\t/\\t/g'
```

So...

```
$ cat file
line0'field0
line1   field1"
$ sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/\\n/g;s/\t/\\t/g' file
line0'field0\nline1\tfield1"
```

*With acknowledgement to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n-using-sed*

### Answer to original wording

If I understand the question correctly, I think you’re looking for something like this (this is in bash}:

```
$ doublequoted="line0'field0\nline1\tfield1\""
$ foo="$(echo -e "${doublequoted//\\/\\\\}")"
$ echo $foo
line0'field0\nline1\tfield1"
```

If I’ve misunderstood, please clarify what you’re looking for.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, looks like my question was easy to misunderstand. The output is correct, it's just that I don't have access to the backslash sequences themselves, but they are already in the form of newlines, tabs, etc. in my variable.

Answer (score 0):

With bash, you could use the builtin `printf`, just being careful about `%` characters:

```bash
doublequoted="line0'field0\nline1\tfield1\"%s"
printf -v interpreted "${doublequoted//%/%%}"
```

then

```
$ declare -p doublequoted interpreted
declare -- doublequoted="line0'field0\\nline1\\tfield1\"%s"
declare -- interpreted="line0'field0
line1   field1\"%s"

$ printf "%s" "$interpreted" | od -c
0000000   l   i   n   e   0   '   f   i   e   l   d   0  \n   l   i   n
0000020   e   1  \t   f   i   e   l   d   1   "   %   s
0000034
```

---

EDIT to match updated requirements

```
$ cat text
line0'field0
line1   field1"

$ cat -A text           # show tabs
line0'field0$
line1^Ifield1"$

$ contents=$(< text)    # slurp the file contents into a var

$ printf -v escaped '%q' "$contents"    # "shell-escape" it

$ echo "$escaped"                       # it's in ANSI-C quoted form
$'line0\'field0\nline1\tfield1"'

$ echo "${escaped#$}"                   # output as requested
'line0\'field0\nline1\tfield1"'
```

Comment: Sorry, I could have phrased my question better. I hope with my new edit I've made clear what I want. Still there are a few nice shell scripting features in your answer that I can learn from.

Comment: Oh, so you want the opposite of this: if the string contains a newline, change it to `\n`, right?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant with "escaped escape sequences", maybe there's a better word for that.

Comment: Are yougoing to edit your answer to match the edited question? I'd like to know the answer, too.

Comment: @Melab have a look